# TesseractOCRiOS pod integration errors ios sdk

Tags: ios, tesseract

I installed cocoa pod for Tesseract. I followed the instructions as specified but I couldn't figure out how to fix these error.
Link for how to integrate https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

Any idea??

warning: no rule to process file 'desktop/text/Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/lib/liblept.a' of type archive.ar for architecture i386
warning: no rule to process file 'desktop/text/Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/lib/libtesseract_all.a' of type archive.ar for architecture i386

Any help would be appreciated.